# Static library's Prefix header not referred

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios6

I have define some default values in My static library's Prefix header and using in a category. When I compile the library stand alone it compiles fine. but when I attached the library to a projects it compliance variable not defined. I am pretty sure I have missed something when I attaching library.

This is how I attached the Library - I dragged and dropped static library project on to the new project and added dependency. I am wondering what was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Build setting of the main Project(not the static Library). 
Search for "`other Linker Flags`" add `-ObjC`
You have to add this flag in the targets as well.

some other useful flags description for static library

**-all_load** Loads all members of static archive libraries.

**-ObjC** Loads all members of static archive libraries that implement an Objective-C class or category.

**-force_load** (path_to_archive) Loads all members of the specified static archive library. Note: -all_load forces all members of all archives to be loaded. This option allows you to target a specific archive.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Red Devil I added all three one by one in both library and app projects. Still no luck.

Comment: Sorry. Actually you don't need to add a flag in Static library. You need to add in the main project(both project and Target). You have to make sure to add library search header path as well. I will edit my answer as well.